# Prove that RX is an ideal of R

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $X$ a non-empty subset of $R$.

Prove that $RX$ is an ideal of $R$.

My attempt was to use the axioms of ideals to prove this, but to no luck maybe i'm missing something could someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you denote $RX$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $R$ is commutative the elements of $RX$ have the form $r_1x_1 + r_2x_2 + \cdots + r_kx_k$. The difference of any two such elements is again such a combination so $RX$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $R$. Furthermore if $r \in R$ then the fact that $RX$ is a left ideal is immediate, while the right follows from the commutivity of $R$.